# rails query Timeout::Error: execution expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rack

I have one simple query, but its showing the **Timeout::Error: execution expired**, also i am using rack::timeout

```
SELECT  SUM(total_checks) as totalcheck FROM "orders"  WHERE 
(orders.order_status_id NOT IN (15, 17)) AND (orders.check_id = 36) AND 
(orders.pass_id = '49') AND (orders.created_at BETWEEN '2016-02-29 
22:00:00.000000' AND '2016-03-02 22:00:00.000000') LIMIT 1
```

also, i have total orders around 9762797, **is there any issue with this query?**

Got when did that explain analyze

```
----------
Limit  (cost=153.76..153.77 rows=1 width=5) (actual time=14622.323..14622.324
rows=1 loops=1)
->  Aggregate  (cost=153.76..153.77 rows=1 width=5) (actual 
time=14622.322..14622.322 rows=1 loops=1)

 ->  Index Scan using idx_orders_check_and_pass on orders 
(cost=0.43..153.76 rows=1 width=5) (actual time=2739.717..14621.649 rows=141 
loops=1)
       Index Cond: ((check_id = 36) AND (pass_id = 49))
       Filter: ((order_status_id <> ALL ('{15,17}'::integer[])) AND 
(created_at >= '2016-02-29 22:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND 
(created_at <= '2016-03-02 22:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
       Rows Removed by Filter: 42396
Total runtime: 14622.524 ms

(7 rows)
```

Comment: Could you run your query with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and send the result?

Comment: thanks, yes i have updated the question with that result

Answer (score 1):

You have quite big table to run `SUM` on. I would suggest to use some caching mechanism to avoid using this query, because 14 seconds is a lot.

For example, I would suggest creating new table `total_orders_checks` and store total checks there. You would need to update it every time you update `orders` table `total_checks` value and it might not suit your app design, but you'll definitely get `total_checks` out of it much faster.

Comment: @amtest well, if you need to just enlarge timeout you can, but I would strongly advise not to do that. Your app shouldn't wait for DB for 14 seconds, that's too much